# how to integrate LINQ

Tags: asp.net

I am working on three tier application.
1.UI
2.BUZ
3.SQL

I want to integrate LINQ in existing application , can any body suggest what should i have to do for integration LINQ.

Could any body send code or example for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Linq to SQL in your data layer

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx